# What's the Node's execution order in this example

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

The common example of presenting the functionality of setImmediate function in Node JS is the following code

```js
console.log('1');
setImmediate(() => console.log('2'));
console.log('3');
```

which evaluates to

```
1
3
2
```

As far as I know setImmediate callbacks are executed during `check` phase of event loop

[image: node js event loop]

However I don't understand where fetching new, sequential instruction fits there? Are we guaranteed that Node will fetch and execute `console.log('3')` BEFORE executing the check phase and therefore print `3` before `2`? If so - how many such instruction would Node execute before reaching `check` phase?

Comment: Doesn't answer question, but keep in mind: general rule of the asynchronous callbacks and operations - you just shouldn't do any assumptions about this. Instead, write your code in a way that it is agnostic to the order of the execution :)

Comment: It's simple run-to-completion instead of preemption. The sequential instructions are just getting executed before the event loop turns to the next phase.

Comment: When does the event loop starts its cycle than? Does it has to execute all the instruction in the given module before the first iteration?

Comment: `console.log(1)`, `setImmediate()` and `console.log(3)` happen before the event loop. The event loop is **only** entered when there is no more javascript to execute. So the interpreter enters the event loop after `console.log(3)`. Once inside the event loop one of the phases will execute `console.log(2)` that is scheduled by `setImmediate()`. As such it does not matter at all which phase of the event loop executes `console.log(2)` you just need to understand that the event loop only happens at the **end** of all scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However I don't understand where fetching new, sequential instruction fits there?

No need to fetch anything new because all the instructions have to be loaded already at that point, since we are already in the middle of executing them!

1. It is determined that your code should run
2. Your code (all 3 lines) runs
3. Event loop is entered and checks what else is there to do
4. It is determined that the callback should run
5. The callback (all "1 lines") runs
6. ...

> Are we guaranteed that Node will fetch and execute console.log('3') BEFORE executing the check phase and therefore print 3 before 2?

Yes.

> If so - how many such instruction would Node execute before reaching check phase?

Infinitely many.

JavaScript is single-threaded* and there nothing can preempt your code (other than a Ctrl+C).

So, the following code will keep outputting `3` in all eternity and *never* get to `2`**:

```js
console.log('1');
setImmediate(() => console.log('2'));
while (true) {
  console.log('3');
}
```

```
1
3
3
3
3
... (forever)
```

Similarly, the following code will for all eternity print `2A` and never get to `2B`:

```js
console.log('1');
setImmediate(() => {
  while (true) {
    console.log('2A');
  }
});
setImmediate(() => console.log('2B'));
console.log('3');
```

```
1
3
2A
2A
2A
2A
... (forever)
```

(The same applies if you were to move the `setImmediate(() => console.log('2B'));` inside the first callback instead of putting it below it.)

**: Yes there are worker threads in node.js and service workers in the browser, but they live in their own environments.*

***: ...consuming 100% of one CPU core in the process and not reacting to any events or signals, so consider this an example of academic interest only, not something you would ever write in real code.*